# How do I detect mobile devices on IIS so I can redirect them to a mobile-specific site?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis-7

Is there a way in IIS of detecting a user is browsing via a mobile device [maybe by checking their User Agent against a list?] so they can be redirected to a mobile-specific website? Or would this logic have to occur at the application level?
Note: All websites involved are HTTPS.

It's IIS 7 running on Windows Sever 2008 R2

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/1941/1918

Comment: Detect and Redirect Mobile Users With IIS URL Rewrite: http://wuleicanada.github.io/blog/2015/05/01/detect-and-redirect-mobile-users-with-iis-url-rewrite/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of detection is usually done with a script on a web page, however it's possible to do some URL rewriting on IIS with a third-party software: http://www.isapirewrite.com/

Comment: Thanks for this info - we already did the redirection at web page level but were asked about doing it in IIS (something we were told Apache could do easily). Your link jogged the memory that we also have the following available:  http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/460/using-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 5):

Here's a rule you can use in IIS 7.5 with the URL Rewrite 2.0 module installed.

```
    <rule name="Mobile Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-Device-User-Agent}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
        <add input="{HTTP_X-OperaMini-Phone-UA}" pattern="midp|mobile|phone" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://mysite.mobi" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
    </rule>
```

Example is copied from http://forums.iis.net/t/1169853.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I think this code doesn't support some symbian phones , palm phones , Zune player and ipod touch browsers.

example (Zune browser) : 
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; XBLWP7; ZuneWP7)

example (SymbianOS v9.1):
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (SymbianOS/9.1; U; [en-us]) AppleWebKit/413 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/413

Answer (score 0):

You can find mobile detection code (based on user agent) for IIS, ASP, ASP.NET and many more on http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/. Here is their suggestion for IIS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <clear />
        <rule name="MobDedect" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="   (android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino" />
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}"    pattern="^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-)" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="http://detectmobilebrowser.com/mobile" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```